# How to loop through the SupportedCultures of a Silverlight 4 project

Tags: silverlight-4.0, localization

I'm doing a localization project and adding a lot of SupportCultures to my project file, e.g

```
<SupportedCultures>
en, de, es, fr, ja, zh-CN
</SupportedCultures>
```

In code, I am displaying a binding to a CultureViewModel and I need to make a CultureInfo obbject for each supported culture. Instead of doing this manually I would like to iterate through the collection in the project file - is there anyway to access these values in code?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [blog entry](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2009/11/13/silverlight-tip-enumerating-embedded-resources.aspx). It shows how to enumerate the contents of a XAP file (it actually downloads one but you should simply open the AppManifest.xaml file from your own XAP).

Iterating over all AssemblyPart tags will give the list of all files making up the XAP file. All parts with a Source attribute ending in "resources.dll" will be one of the supported cultures. Its abbreviated name is the directory name of this part.

Comment: Hi Timores, I was actually hoping there would be an easy way of reading the actual project file, SupportedCultures XML node (Something like App.SupportedCultures ;)

Comment: I 100% agree, but I could not find something like that.